# Removing lowercase letters and moving punctuation at the end of string

Tags: python

I have a Pig Latin translator which works, but I must now figure out a way to lowercase any uppercase words in the middle of each word and move any punctuation in the middle of each word to the end.

I have experimented with

```
if letter_index.isupper():
   new_word = letter_index.lower()
```

but this does not work.  And I have imported `string` and created:

```
punc = string.punctuation
```

Here is what I have:

```
import string

    def part2():
      fin = open('Sonnet.txt')
      vowels = 'AEIOUaeiou'
      #punc = string.punctuation
      for line in fin:
        poem = line.split()
        print(poem)
        for word in poem:
          for letter_index in range(len(word)): 
            if word[letter_index] in vowels:
              if letter_index == 0:
                if letter_index.isupper():
                  new_word = letter_index.lower()
                  print(new_word + 'way') 
              else:
            print(word[letter_index:]+word[0:letter_index] + 'ay')
            break
part2()
```

Any uppercase words with uppercase letters in the middle should be lowercase but the first letter should now be uppercase.  Any punctuation in the middle of the word should then be moved to the end of the word.

Comment: What is the best way to complete the code?

Comment: Look at [`str.title()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.title) and [`str.capitalize()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.capitalize)

Comment: Any ideas on how to apply those methods?

Comment: Yep, you just call them on the string that you want to apply them to: `‘aBcD’.capitalize() == ‘Abcd’`

Comment: To move the punctuation I'd likely use regular expressions... looking for non letters

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sentence = 'pyThon jAva cpP'
words_list = sentence.split(' ')
prpoer_word_list = [w.title() for w in words_list]
print(' '.join(prpoer_word_list))
```

Output

```
Python Java Cpp
```

Comment: I don’t think you even need to split the string for `str.title()`, it will capitalize each word in the string.